# how to structure our django model

Tags: django

I am doing online shopping project in django.
I split my project into Admin app, moderator app, shop app.

There are two types of product- one inserted by moderator and other by registered shops.

do i need to create separate product models for both app,

If I try to give one common product table inside admin app, there will be issue with foreign key.

So how I will create product model, separate(one in moderator app and in shop app) or common (in admin app)

same issue with order models and stock models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.Foreignkey(User, null=True, blank=True, ondelete=models.CASCADE)
    shop = models.Foreignkey(Shop, null=True, blank=True, ondelete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.Charfield(max_length = 50)
    ...
```

if user and shop will be added then it will be considered as registered shop's products if user and shop is blank then it will be considered that product in inserted by moderator.

Comment: but where I will place the model. can I place it in AdminApp by making it common?

Answer (score 0):

Several solutions are possible:

1. you can create a model of your Product model (abstract or not, it depends if you need to request all the Products in your DB) and inherit from it to create a ShopProduct with a shop FK and another ModeratorProduct with a moderator FK
2. you can use a generic FK in the Product model https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations to provide relation with Shop or Moderator
3. you can provide two FKs to your model (Shop and Moderator) and only define one for every product.